# Android ListView inside ScrollView - Alternatives and suggestions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-scrollview, android-screen-support

In my Android app I have a layout for an activity which consists of a TableLayout on top and one custom ListView below. However, in landscape mode the listview is not completely displayed. So I think I need to add a scrollview to be able to see the full layout.
However, from what I read it is not possible to put a listview inside a scrollview in Android.
What are the alternatives to solve my problem? Thank you so much

Comment: Can you post your layout code? And possibly screenshots?

Comment: Yup, in Android you should only have one scrolling element. You should either make your whole layout scrollable (everything inside the ScrollView) or make your layout compact enough for the ListView to be the only scrolling View.

Comment: @thomas88wp is correct, that's why we need to see your layout code in order to determine what can be done to achieve your desired results. It may be that you need to create a separate layout for landscape orientation (and put it in the res/layout-land/ directory), or that you can modify your current layout to get what you want.